# Android SDK is Unavailable Upon First Startup of Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I've been trying to install Android Studio for use in creating a React Native app using Expo. As I try to install Android Studio, and run it for the first time, I arrive at the following screen:

[image: The image says that "Before continuing, you must download the necessary components or select an existing SDK]

Keep in mind, I have not yet separately installed an SDK (I'm unsure of how to).
I click the "Next" button and come to this screen:

[image: This image tells me that I need to click the checkbox to update or install the Android SDK, but it also says that this Android SDK installation/update is unavailable]

I am unsure of where to go from here. Do I install Android SDK, and if so, how?

EDIT: If I skip through these steps, clicking "Next" until I go to the main page, and I attempt to start a new project, this comes up:

[image: Image of "Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK" saying that "The Android SDK location cannot be at filesystem root"]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is an issue with your network.

Actually you should be able to see a list of all the available sdks as you can see in the image I attached.

[screenshot of settings screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fGPc.png)

Comment: Yes, thank you. I realized that my firewall was blocking a few key access points for the setup process. I removed those, and it works now. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you please tell me what you did to resolve the issue @IPSDSILVA

Comment: @TechTrivia Go to windows firewall setting and selecte the "Allow an app through the firewall" option and than check the android studio app if its not shown in the list than click on change settings and than select allow other app option and select tha android studio exe file.

Answer (score 9):

I was on the company computer and had the VPN connected. Disconnected the VPN and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Go to System Settings > HTTP Proxy,
Select Auto-detect proxy settings to use an automatic proxy configuration URL for the proxy settings,
close your android studio and start it as administrator and check it again

Answer (score 3):

Google may block you and you don't access to these addresses:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-1.xml
...
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-5.xml

use a good VPN and change setting of android studio proxy as what "Mahdi Zareei" said :

> Go to System Settings > HTTP Proxy, Select Auto-detect proxy settings
> to use an automatic proxy configuration URL for the proxy settings,
> close your android studio and start it again

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Settings > HTTP Proxy, Select Auto-detect proxy settings and save it. Once done restart android studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error running at home, no firewall etc.

I was re-installing and still had ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT defined; I unset these and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This means you cannot reach Google servers where the SDK is downloaded from.

You can use a good VPN. If your connection is fast, try that free vpn gate. You can also try connecting from the network at University.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly, I had to create an empty Android folder and an empty sdk folder inside of it. Then I was able to change the sdk directory path to be the empty Android folder, and it allowed me to install it

Answer (score 0):

I’had thesame problem, I just stopped the installation and resumed while crushing the previous one. Everything was fine later on.
I think before going into proxy you should try to resume, in my case I began installation and due to bad connection it stopped and asked me to chose a proxy first, when connection was stable again I cancelled proxy option and proceeded then it showed "sdk unavailable" message, so I cancelled the whole process and resumed installation from the beginning. It worked fine after that.
You may not have thesame worry though.